# Saving some data on orientation change in Android

Tags: android, device-orientation, orientation-changes

As far as I've understood, your Android activity will be recreated for the new orientation on any orientation changes.

Is there a way to store / save some of the data from the original orientation upon the orientation change?

I'd like to store some Bitmaps, so I don't have to load it again on the orientation change.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using static variables/classes is a bad approach in terms of maintainability and debugging.

---

I have been using `Activity.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` but I found out just now that this is deprecated (probably since honeycomb or later). 
[Activity.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29)

Using this method, just call `Activity.getLastNonConfigurationInstance` to retrieve the same object you returned in the `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`. Be sure to check for null and cast to the right class (you can return/get any class). [Activity.getLastNonConfigurationInstance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLastNonConfigurationInstance%28%29)

A sample usage in pseudo-code would be:

```
onRetainNonConfigurationInstance:
    return "I need to remember this next time";

onCreate:
    ...
    String messageToShow = null;
    Object data = getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
    if(data != null)
        messageToShow = (String)data;
    else
        messageToShow = "Nothing to show";
```

---

So, if you are targetting up to 2.x.x you can use that method. Otherwise, google recommends you to use `Fragment.setRetainInstance`. This is backwards compatible via the compability package.

[Fragment.setRetainInstance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29)

Comment: @Pedro Loureiro But this doesn't work for an Activity, only a Fragement, right?

Answer (score 5):

Save the items in a parent activity or static utility class.

Otherwise, you can use the manifest to tell the app to not destroy the activity on screen resizes.  Check out this article: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me a lot and I think I can solve my problem now :-) I will mark this as answered when I can in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a very nice article on the Android Developer site which covers this topic.

> Some devices, like the T-Mobile G1, can change their hardware
>   configuration at runtime. For instance, when you open the keyboard,
>   the screen change from the portrait orientation to the landscape
>   orientation.
>
> To make Android app development easier, the Android system
>   automatically handles configuration change events and restarts the
>   current activity with the new configuration.
>
> [...]
>
> While this behavior is really powerful, since your application adapts
>   automatically to the device's configuration at runtime, it is
>   sometimes confusing for new Android developers, who wonder why their
>   activity is destroyed and recreated.
>
> Facing this "issue," *some developers choose to handle configuration
>   changes themselves which is, in general, a short-term solution that
>   will only complicate their lives later.*
>
> [...]

[The full article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html).

Answer (score 0):

Process running your activity will not be restarted. Android framework will just create a new instance of your activity. So as simplest solution you can store your data in static variables.

Comment: So, I could basically create the variables as static and initialize them as null. Then, do a null check and if they're not null, I'll reuse them and if they're null, I'll load them. Correct?

Comment: Be careful about the static variables storage ; you might read this very interesting article by Romain Guy : http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/

Answer (score 0):

you can try using sharedpreferences:

`editor edit = preferences.edit();
edit.putString("username", "new_value_for_user");
edit.commit();`